# Been stuck on a test error on Ruby on Rails tutorial- Error: UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I've been stuck on this one for a while and keep getting 2 errors when I rake test. Referencing Listing 9.23 testing point. Any help would be much appreciated.

Test Error:

```
    1) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user_id' for #<UsersControllerTest:0x007fbff6be3120>
    test/test_helper.rb:24:in `log_in_as'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:35:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'


  2) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user_id' for #<UsersControllerTest:0x007fbff6c01850>
    test/test_helper.rb:24:in `log_in_as'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:28:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

29 runs, 66 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips
```

User_Controller_Test file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when not logged in" do
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

test "should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
```

Test_Helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
end

#logs in a test user
def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password = options[:password]       || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
        post login_path, session: { email: user.email,
                                    password: password,
                                    remember_me: remember_me}

else

session[:user_id] = user_id
 end
end

private
#returns true inside an int. test
def integration_test?
    defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And where does user_id come from here?

```
def log_in_as(user, options = {})
  ... 
  if integration_test?
    ...
  else
    session[:user_id] = user_id
  end
end
```

Seems it should be:

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```